# EPIPE Error when uploading large file using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I was following [this](https://pagep.net/2018/03/31/how-to-handle-large-file-upload-with-nodejs-express-server/) article to setup a nodejs server on my local machine (which has 16 gb memory and about 170gb free disk-space) and uploaded a 20 gb file, for the first couple of times the file got uploaded successfully, but after a while i started getting EPIPE error:

```
error FetchError: request to http://localhost:3200/upload failed, reason: write EPIPE
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Volumes/FreeAgent GoFlex Drive/Test/multer-project/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1455:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:467:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:100:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'EPIPE',
  code: 'EPIPE'
}
```

When i checked, the file got uploaded partially and was about 28mb in size. I tried uploading the file from both Postman, browser and a nodejs script, but got the same EPIPE error message. I am not sure why is this happening, googling the error message didn't help. I am not sure how to overcome this. Following is my server and client code.

```
// server.js
const express = require("express"); // Express Web Server
const busboy = require("connect-busboy"); // Middleware to handle the file upload https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy
const path = require("path"); // Used for manipulation with path
const fs = require("fs-extra");  

const app = express(); // Initialize the express web server
app.use(
  busboy({
    highWaterMark: 2 * 1024 * 1024 // Set 2MiB buffer
  })
); // Insert the busboy middle-ware

const uploadPath = path.join(__dirname, "uploads/"); // Register the upload path
fs.ensureDir(uploadPath); // Make sure that he upload path exits

/**
 * Create route /upload which handles the post request
 */
app.route("/upload").post((req, res, next) => {
  req.pipe(req.busboy); // Pipe it trough busboy

  req.busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename) => {
    console.log(`Upload of '${filename}' started`);

    // Create a write stream of the new file
    const fstream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(uploadPath, filename));
    // Pipe it trough
    file.pipe(fstream);

    // On finish of the upload
    fstream.on("close", () => {
      console.log(`Upload of '${filename}' finished`);
      res.send("ok");
    });
  });
});

/**
 * Serve the basic index.html with upload form
 */
app.route("/").get((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
  res.write(
    '<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'
  );
  res.write('<input type="file" name="fileToUpload"><br>');
  res.write('<input type="submit">');
  res.write("</form>");
  return res.end();
});

const server = app.listen(3200, function() {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

and my client code is:

```
// client.js
const fs = require("fs");
const FormData = require("form-data");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append(
  "file",
  fs.createReadStream("/Users/phantom007/My Documents/35gb.myfile")
);

var requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  body: formdata,
  redirect: "follow"
};

fetch("http://localhost:3200/upload", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

After strugging for a long time i figured out that this error was coming because the number of bytes getting written on the same is larger than the number of bytes sent to the server, so in my client code, i changed

this

```
  fs.createReadStream("/Users/phantom007/My Documents/35gb.myfile")
```

to this

```
fs.createReadStream("/Users/phantom007/My Documents/35gb.myfile", { highWaterMark: 2 * 1024 * 1024 })
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to add high timeout on google api:

```
google.options({ timeout: 5 * 60 * 1000 }); // 5 minutes
```

With this the error changed that I didn't activate youtube API so enabling that fixed the issue.
To enable I had to go to this link:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=my_project_id

Make sure you replace the my_project_id